# Azure DevOps alternative to Octopus Deploy runbooks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-automation

I am using Azure pipelines for deployments, but also would like to have option to automate operational tasks like i can do it on Octopus Deploy Runbooks.

Operational tasks are like restart services, restart servers in particular order, automate configuration change for the service, etc.

While googling i found Azure Automation, but looks like to implement this i will have to maintain 2 separate environments/infrastructures/set of deployment targets. I mean deployment targets needs to be defined for both Azure DevOps and Azure Automation. I would like to have single environment and use it for both Deployments and running those automated tasks which would not be deployments as described above.

Sorry if my question is not clear, hopefully i managed to explain it well :)

Comment: Azure DevOps is not for environment management, although I have seen many people using it for that purpose. You can do all of those operational tasks in Azure DevOps if you want to take that path though. You can actually keep all of your environment /deployment variables in a YAML file in Git and have both DevOps and some other service use that same information.